# When I edit without data! but rails console can show it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My rails project database is imported from MSSQL. I am using MariaDB version 11.2.2. When I press the Edit button, the web form has no data, but when I use the Rails Console to issue commands, the data can be displayed. How can I troubleshoot?

Ruby 2.7.7
Rails 5.2.8.1

[image]

[image]

I use rails console & mysql command, make sure data is exist, but when I use web-base to manipulate it, it dispear!

[image]

I'm not sure it about UTF8mb3 or UTF8mb4, and most of record is normal, a few is dispear!

[image]